# Changing label texts on WizardForm page in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to change (in code) the text of certain labels on the `WizardForm` of the installer which are NOT exposed by the `WizardForm`.

Example:

```
ReadyLabel2a=Click Install to continue with the installation, or click Back if you want to review or change any settings.
```

I cannot do `WizardForm.ReadyLabel2a.Caption := 'BLAH';` as the compiler complains about unknown identifier `ReadyLabel2a`.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All components of the installer wizard form are exposed.

The label is `ReadyLabel`, not `ReadyLabel2a`. The `ReadyLabel2a` is ID of the message. The installer uses either message `ReadyLabel2a` or `ReadyLabel2b` for the `ReadyLabel`, depending on the setup configuration.

```pascal
WizardForm.ReadyLabel.Caption := 'BLAH';
```

See [`TWizardForm` class declaration](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm).

---

You can find how the messages are used in controls in [Inno Setup source code](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/)

---

If you need to have an installer specific texts for certain standard messages, modify the texts using [`Messages` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
ReadyLabel2a=Click Install to continue with the installation, or click Back if you want to review or change any settings.
```

Comment: Thanks... I was able to solve my issues with your help.