# How to reuse/modify the license dialog for own purpose

Tags: inno-setup

During install I need to show the license dialog (with the two radio buttons).
So very similar like the license dialog but with other text content (in text field and headers etc.)

So is it possible to reuse the license dialog? 
With changing the top/header lines ... because it's not a "license agreement".

If not I will create a custom window/dialog for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[Messages]` section to modify the standard labels of any standard page.

See [Changing label texts on WizardForm page in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33796500/850848)

In this particular case, you are interested in the following messages:

```
[Messages]
WizardLicense=Some description
LicenseLabel3=Please read the following text. You must accept it before continuing with the installation.
LicenseAccepted=I &accept this
LicenseNotAccepted=I &do not this
```

[image]